# "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" in odd place--C++

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers, lvalue

NOTE: This is NOT a duplicate of the billion and one questions with this name in the title. This has to do with pointers and very odd stuff, not an accidental `=` instead of `==`.

I have a C++ function in which I have a `void*` argument called `out`. I have this line:

```
(char*)out=new char[*size];
```

Where `size` in a `uint32_t*`. The compiler complains:

```
fundemental_bin_types.h:55:32: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you need the cast (`(char*)`) here?

Comment: `(char*)`? `void*`, Passing a POD by pointer? `new char[]`? Are you *sure* this is C++?

Comment: Yes. Just very odd C++. Very odd C++. This is part of a set of functions that have to be referenced by a function pointer. They all need to be able to return any kind of data, but only they and the end caller knows the type. The intermediate code (my main code) has no idea what the types are, so we have to pass things like `int`s and `char`s as `void*`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(char*)out` is *not* an lvalue (`out` itself may be but the cast changes things), the cast belongs on the other side of the assignment and you're casting to a void pointer rather than a char pointer:

```
out = (void*) (new char[*size]);
```

In any case, `void*` is implicitly convertible from other pointers so you can get away with just:

```
out = new char[*size];
```

Comment: Why do you think a cast is required at all?

Answer (score 1):

C pointer casts create an lvalue; C++ pointer casts do not unless you cast to a reference type. I.e., the following should compile:

```
(char *&)out= new char[*size];
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `(char*)` as it serves no purpose here.  (Or it serves some purpose that you haven't explained.)

If you have a void* argument you can't simply assign to it (in order to have that pointer seen by the caller) like you could a `void*&` argument.